# Using templates for creating PDF files

Tags: java, itext

I have some PDF template (with header and footer). I want to generate documents that are based on that template.

Is there any way to do that with iText? Thank you

P.S. Right now I am generate a document on-fly i.e. every time I generate header, footer and the context itself.

UPDATE: I have found incredible library called [PD4ML](http://pd4ml.com/). It's not free, but not such expensive, BUT it has really cool features such as HTML2PDF conversion on fly, supports a lot of HTML-CSS tags and has even its own jsp tags library! So I really suggest it when you need something instead of heavy and memory-eating JasperReports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) library and the [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport) visual designer.
JasperReports use iText to produce PDFs from "jasper" templates, that are XML files (following the jrxml DTD) compiled in java classes, but allows you to use the template for generating MS Office files (with POI), html, etc.

Comment: Does JasperReports supports hibernate objects? I mean can I pass hibernate object as a datasource to jasperreports?

Comment: JR has a DataSource abstraction: it can query directly in SQL through JDBC or other various connectivity library, amongst which, if I remember well, hibernate with HQL. However you can pass a generic collection of JavaBeans, the more abstract datasource I think, at which at last evrything reconducts to.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure with iText, but you can use BIRT for this purpose. http://www.eclipse.org/birt/ Its too much using it just for PDF creation, you can do a lot (more than you can imagine) with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can choose your template format. I would go with JODReport and JODConverter.

JODReport use an ODT template and fill the mapping in the template with your java code.

JODConverter use LibreOffice to convert such template in PDF or whatever fortmat LibreOffice can handle to export.

You have to be able to use LibreOffice as a service installed remotely on a machine.

I used it back in 2012 but not sure if the project is still active